# How to send mail in every five minute using database data in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How i can send mail in regular interval using database data in mvc3

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why would you do this - surely a dedicated process eg windows service would be more appropriate?

Comment: Why would you need to use MVC to create and send an email? Just write a PowerShell (or VBScript) and let the Task Scheduler run it.

Comment: Anything job/task based like a scheduler should be created as a windows service

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, one good way of doing it to write a web service to do it and schedule it using  [Quartz Schduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [MvcMailer NuGet package](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145629/Announcing-MvcMailer-Send-Emails-Using-ASP-NET-MVC). It allows you to render MVC View as Email Body

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Timer and start it in application start
My Sample:

in Global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new Timer with Interval set to 300 seconds(5 Minutes).
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5 * 60 * 1000);
    aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
    aTimer.Start();
}
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
//Send Email;
}
```

### Update Answer

How to send Mail:

```
var mailObj = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
//if your host has smtp server
var SMTPServer = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("localhost"); 
//if your host has not smtp server and you want use gmail
var googleSMTPServer = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gmailAddress@Gmail.com", "gmailPassword")
};

try
{
    SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
    // OR
    googleSMTPServer.Send(mailObj); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //
}
```

### Note

jgauffin has right! The app pool can be recycled at any time. if your site has not any visitor in 20 minute, IIS automaticaly stop app pool. you can disable it in IIS

Comment: Don't use ASP.NET to perform continuous tasks. The app pool can be recycled at any time.